# How to get handle to an event that may cause my application to go in hang state

Tags: windbg, crash-dumps, sos

I am doing a dump file analyis for an application hang problem. Here is one interesting line from the stack trace.

```
0bc2f3e4 75a8bd1e 0bc2f298 0bc2f30c 00000001 ntdll!KiFastSystemCallRet
0bc2f32a 6a393c42 00000001 7ffdf000 00000001 kernel32!WaitForMultipleObjectsEx+0x8e
```

Looking at [WaitForMultipleObjectEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms687028%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) description in MSDN, the second parameter is const HANDLE *lpHandles. This make me thing that I should be able to do a !handle 7ffdf000 to figure out which event is it waiting for but when I do that, I get following

Type    Error retrieving type

Any ideas what I may be doing wrong here or any tips on getting more details on cause of hang?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second parameter is pointer to array of HANDLE's. In your case, since the size of array is 1, you should be able to dump the handle using command
`!handle poi 7ffdf000`

Comment: Thanks. It gives me back Handle 08000000. Any ideas what does this mean? If I run !handle 08000000; it just gives me same result (Handle 08000000).

Comment: The address 08000000 looks wierd, not sure that is correct value for handle, they are usually smaller integers. One more thing. Since you are working with a dump dile, you need to have dump file created with handle information in it. Commands are `.dump /mh` or `.dump /ma`.

Comment: Ok. Try typing `!handle 08000000 7`. That would print more verbose information on the handle.

Comment: !handle 08000000 7
Handle 08000000
  Type          <Error retrieving type>
unable to query object information
unable to query object information

Comment: The dump file was generated by right clicking on the process name in Processed Tab under Task manager. Also when I run the !handle command it displays long list which makes me think that it contains handles information

Answer (score 0):

What about "dd 7ffdf000"? and the first I4 is the handle.