# How to get the handle from the function of KERNELBASE!WaitForMultipleObjectsEx when using windbg debugging

Tags: .net, deadlock, windbg

My asp.net application hanged. So I scratched a dump file. I posted a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24596550/will-net-parallel-tasks-exhaust-all-the-threads-in-the-pool-and-cause-dead-lock).
Now In this new post, I want to find out the lock handle.

```
0:177> kb 5
RetAddr           : Args to Child                                                           : Call Site
000007fe`fda11430 : 00000001`012f8bb8 00000000`00000000 000007fe`f1651000 000007fe`f1f00d1f : ntdll!NtWaitForMultipleObjects+0xa
00000000`77851723 : 00000000`0d67b0f8 00000000`0d67b0f0 00000000`00000000 00000000`0d67af50 : KERNELBASE!WaitForMultipleObjectsEx+0xe8
000007fe`fa2f0f15 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`0763d720 00000000`00000001 : kernel32!WaitForMultipleObjectsExImplementation+0xb3
000007fe`fa2f0cee : 00000000`00000001 00000000`0763d8e8 00000000`00000001 00000000`0763d8e8 : clr!WaitForMultipleObjectsEx_SO_TOLERANT+0x91
000007fe`fa2f0b79 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`0d67b2c9 00000000`0763d720 00000000`0d67b4c8 : clr!Thread::DoAppropriateAptStateWait+0x56
```

The stacktrace is posted above. From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7285037/how-to-get-handle-to-an-event-that-may-cause-my-application-to-go-in-hang-state) and [here](http://weblogs.thinktecture.com/ingo/2006/08/who-is-blocking-that-mutex---fun-with-windbg-cdb-and-kd.html) , I learned how to try to find the handle, but I have some barrier:
1) the kb command displays the first three parameters. but I see four parameters that are splitted by the space.

```
00000000`0d67b0f8 00000000`0d67b0f0 00000000`00000000 00000000`0d67af50
```

I mess up and don't know which parameter is the handle and which represents the handle length.

Supporse the handle is 00000000`0d67b0f0, and the length is 00000000`0d67b0f8. If I input

```
dd 00000000`0d67b0f0 L?00000000`0d67b0f8
```

Will this ouput show the handle address?
I tried to type into the command, but the output is toooo long. I can't find the handle address.
I tried

```
dd 00000000`0d67b0f0 L1
```

but, also didn't find the handle.

Does somebody can help me?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I also find [DebugDiag 2.1](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42933) is quite good in analyzing deadlocks. Might be easier than doing it in WinDbg manually.

Comment: <quote> 1) the kb command displays the first three parameters. but I see four parameters that are splitted by the space. </quote> in x64 you cannot rely on this the first 4 parameters are passed via registers what you are looking at can be irrelevent  unless the arguments were saved to homespace in stack (by using /homeparams switch while compiling)

Comment: @ThomasW. Thank your post. I have use DebugDiag2.1 to analyze the deadlock, but there is no deadlock detected. I hava another question posted to seek answer. That question is about "[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24596550/will-net-parallel-tasks-exhaust-all-the-threads-in-the-pool-and-cause-dead-lock): will .net Parallel Tasks exhaust all the threads in the pool and cause dead lock, the app hanged, incoming request can't be processed?"

Answer (score 1):

`length` obviously cannot be 000000000d67b0f8, it's too much. Also you are looking at the wrong function. I have no idea what the arguments to `KERNELBASE!WaitForMultipleObjectsEx` are or what calling convention it uses, it's not public API. You need to look at the line below that, which refers to a call to `kernel32!WaitForMultipleObjectsExImplementation`. Its arguments look much more more like the arguments to `WaitForMultipleObjectsEx`: the first argument, `length`, is 1, which is reasonable, the next is a pointer to the array of handles and the rest are zero. So it seems that you need to dump the first `HANDLE`, that is `ULONG_PTR`, at the address `000000000763d720`.